# Calcular valores em real R$

Tags: javascript

Alguém poderia me ajudar a calcular os valores em centavos, transformar o valor *1.6* em *1.60*.

Código:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $entrada = 0,
        $saida = 0,
        $total = 0;
    $.each($("td[name='entrada']"), function() {
        $entrada += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(",", "."));
    });
    $.each($("td[name='saida']"), function() {
        $saida += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(",", "."));
    });
    $total = $entrada - $saida;
    $("#totalEntrada").append("R$ " + $entrada);
    $("#totalSaida").append("R$ " + $saida)
    $("#totalGeral").append("R$ " + $total);
});
```

```html
<body>
    <h2>ENTRADA</h2>
    <table width="198" border="1" id="table">
        <tr>
            <td width="39%">PRODUTO</td>
            <td width="12%">VALOR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td name="entrada">100,00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td name="entrada">100,00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h2>SAIDA</h2>
    <table width="196" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="39%">DESCRICAO</td>
            <td width="12%">VALOR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SAIDA</td>
            <td name="saida">50,00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h2>TOTAL</h2>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>TOTAL ENTRADA</td>
        <td id="totalEntrada"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TOTAL SAIDA</td>
        <td id="totalSaida"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TOTAL GERAL</td>
        <td id="totalGeral"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Deu tudo certo? Funcionou?

Answer (score 16):

Se estiver utilizando navegadores modernos, utilize `toLocaleString`:

```
var formato = { minimumFractionDigits: 2 , style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }
$("#totalEntrada").append($entrada.toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
$("#totalSaida").append($saida.toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
$("#totalGeral").append($total.toLocaleString('pt-BR', formato));
```

Dessa forma você não precisa se preocupar com separador decimal (se vai ser vírgula ou ponto) e nem com concatenar o cifrão (R$). Também se precisar mostrar valores em outras moedas é só mudar a localização.

O método `toLocaleString` já é antigo nos navegadores, o que é novo é a implementação da internacionalização. A tabela abaixo mostra quais suportam os parâmetros de localização:

```
Recurso         Chrome  Firefox     Internet Explorer       Opera       Safari (WebKit)
Suporte básico  Sim     Sim         Sim                     Sim         Sim
Localização     24      29          11                      15          Não Suportado
```

No Internet Explorer, por exemplo, em versões menores que a 11, o `toLocaleString` retornaria "1.6" para o código a seguir (a passagem dos parâmetros não dá erro, apenas são ignorados):

```
var numero = 1.6;
var dinheiro = numero.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { minimumFractionDigits: 2 , style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
```

De acordo com o MDN, é possível verificar se o browser tem suporte às opções de internacionalização, usando a seguinte função:

```
function toLocaleStringSupportsLocales() {
   var number = 0;
   try {
     number.toLocaleString('i');
   } catch (e) {
     return e​.name === 'RangeError';
   }
   return false;
}
```

Então, se você determinar que o navegador não possui o suporte adequado, pode reescrever a função `toLocaleString`, de forma capaz de entender formato de moeda da seguinte maneira (ou como melhor te atender):

```
if(!toLocaleStringSupportsLocales()){
    Number.prototype.toLocaleString = function(lingua, opcoes) {
        var numero = this.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",");
        if(!opcoes)
            return numero;

        if(opcoes.style == "currency")
            return "R$ " + numero;        
    }
}
```

Leia mais no [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) ou no [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn412711%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

Nota: não recomendo prefixar as variáveis com `$` quando não forem referências a elementos jQuery.

Comment: Você poderia incrementar sua resposta para contemplar detalhes de compatibilidade cross-browser/server-side desta solução? Muito interessante, desconhecia completamente estes parametros do `toLocaleString`!

Comment: Melhorei minha resposta explicando melhor a questão da compatibilidade e como lidar com ela.

Answer (score 1):

Use esta solução. Além das duas casas decimais e o R$, também aplica pontos a cada bloco de 3 números. Também não depende de libs externas. Fora que usa só uma linha e é totalmente funcional. Vanilla :D

```
const centavosParaReais = centavos => 'R$ ' + (centavos / 100).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',').split('').reverse().map((v, i) => i > 5 && (i + 6) % 3 === 0 ? `${v}.` : v).reverse().join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

## **Só substituir:**

```
$("#totalEntrada").append("R$ " + $entrada);
$("#totalSaida").append("R$ " + $saida)
$("#totalGeral").append("R$ " + $total);
```

## **Por:**

```
$("#totalEntrada").append("R$ " +  Number($entrada).toFixed(2));
$("#totalSaida").append("R$ " +  Number($saida).toFixed(2));
$("#totalGeral").append("R$ " +  Number($total).toFixed(2));
```

Se quiser aumentar para `R$ 1,600`, é só colocar `toFixed(3)`

Comment: Se a cultura do navegador não for pt-BR aparecerá `1.60` ao invés de `1,60`

Comment: Precisa negativar meu post? kkkkk!

Comment: Já desnegativei, antes de você comentar, realmente a solução funciona para a maioria dos casos

Comment: Usando vírgula: `'R$ ' + (+numero).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')`

Comment: Eu acho que não adianta funcionar para a maioria dos casos, tem que funcionar para todos os casos.