# Como aparecer valores formatados no gráfico

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chartjs

Utilizo a seguinte biblioteca para gerar os gráficos:

http://www.chartjs.org

Possuo a seguinte função para formatar dinheiro com ponto e vírgula (retirado de uma resposta aqui do SO) que retorna o valor como tipo `String`:

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
    var n = this, 
        c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
        d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
        t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
        s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
        i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
       return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
};
```

E possuo a seguinte código JavaScript para preencher o gráfico:

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            var dados = [ ];

            var valores_ajax = $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '<c:url value="/link1/link2/link3" />',
                async: false,
                success: function(e){
                    var array_length = e.length;
                    for (var i=0; i < array_length; i++){
                        dados.push(formatOnlyNumber(e[i]));
                    }
                },
                error: function(e){
                    alert(e);
                }
            });

            var data = {
                labels : [ 'labels_vao_aqui1', 'labels_vao_aqui2' ],
                datasets : [ {
                    fillColor : "rgb(153, 237, 139)",
                    strokeColor : "rgb(74, 186, 88)",
                    pointColor : "rgb(74, 186, 88)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    data : dados
                } ]
            }

            var options = {
                animation : true,
                responsive : true,
                margin : '2px',
                backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF'
            };

            var c = $('#idDaDiv');
            var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
            var ctx = document.getElementById("nomeDaDiv")
                    .getContext("2d");

            new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);
        });
```

Se eu formatar diretamente o valor dentro de `dados.push`, irá preencher corretamente o `Array`, porém serão preenchidos os elementos como tipo `String` e não como tipo numérico e assim o gráfico irá se perder ao passar o atributo `data` na construção do `Chart` na linha: `new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, options);`.

Então, gostaria de saber se não tem mais algum atributo como `data` ou `label` que possa passar no gráfico que monte corretamente as barras do gráfico com seus valores porém que ao passar o mouse sobre cima apareça os valores formatados ou outra solução que recomendariam para isso.

Por enquanto mostra assim:

> 10000.00

Invés de:

> 10.000,00

Answer (score 0):

Foi dada a seguinte solução porém o post foi removido, estou postando de novo já que me ajudou, era a solução e agradeço:

**Obs:** O autor da resposta se quiser publicar de novo aqui apago meu post para dar como melhor resposta o seu, quando fui dar um +1 e melhor resposta o mesmo já estava removido.

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function (c, d, t) {
    var n = this,
        c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
        d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
        t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
        s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
        i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "",
        j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
    return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
};

 var options = {
    animation: true,
    responsive: true,   
    tooltipTemplate:
        function (valuesObject) { return "Dia " + valuesObject.label + ": R$ " + valuesObject.value.formatMoney(2, ',', '.'); },
    multiTooltipTemplate:
        function (valuesObject) { return valuesObject.datasetLabel + ": R$ " + valuesObject.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","); },
    scaleLabel:
        function (valuesObject) { return "R$ " + valuesObject.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","); }
};



new Chart(indicadoresMes).Line(result, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Só para adicionar mais uma resposta, eu resolveria assim.

source: [Calcular valores em real R$](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62524/calcular-valores-em-real-r)
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

```js
let valor = 10000.00,
    valor_formatado = valor.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
    
console.info(valor_formatado);
```