# Criar campos de parcelas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para gerar parcelas usando jQuery?

Eu tenho o campo:

- Valor
- Parcelas
- valor pago
- Melhor dia para vencimento

O código pegaria o `valor` e subtrairia pelo `valor pago` com o valor restante geraria as `aparcelas` segundo o `melhor dia para pagamento`.

### - Exemplo:

Estou pagamento R$400,00 em 3x, o vencimento será sempre dia 10.

> 1 -  R$133,33 -  10-08-2019
>
> 2 -  R$133,33 -  10-09-2019
>
> 3 -  R$133,33 -  10-10-2019

Como proceder?

```js
$('#valorCurso, #valorPago, #parcelas, #melhorDia').focusout(function() {
  var valorCurso = $("#valorCurso").val();
  var valorPago = $("#valorPago").val();
  var parcelas = $("#parcelas").val();
  var melhorDia = $("#melhorDia").val();

  if (valorCurso != "" && valorPago != "" && parcelas != "") {
    $('#tabelaParcelas').show();

    valor1 = parseFloat(parseFloat(valorCurso) - parseFloat(valorPago)).toFixed(2);

    valorParcela = valor1 / parcelas;

    var table = '';
    var x = 1;
    while (x <= parcelas) {
      table += '<tr><td>' + x + '</td>';
      table += '<td>data</td>';
      table += '<td> R$' + parseFloat(valorParcela) + '</td></tr>';
      x++;
    }
    $('#tabelaParcelas tbody').html(table);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Valor</label>
        <input id="valorCurso" name="valorCurso" type="text" class="form-control moeda" value="" required/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Valor pago</label>
        <input id="valorPago" name="valorPago" type="text" class="form-control moeda" value="" required/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Parcelas</label>
        <input id="parcelas" name="parcelas" type="number" class="form-control" value="" required/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Melhor dia</label>
        <select id="melhorDia" name="melhorDia" class="form-control">
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>




  <div class="space-4"></div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="clearfix form-actions">
      <label class="control-label">Parcelas</label>

      <table id="tabelaParcelas" style="display:none;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Parcela</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Data</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Mas a quantidade de parcelas não é o cliente que escolhe?

Comment: Como assim gerar a quantidade de parcelas de acordo com o melhor dia?

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus Se for 3 parcelas a pessoa digita no campo `parcelas` e ira ser gerado 3 parcelas.

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus Melhor dia, seria o melhor dia para quela fatura vender, Vamos supor que eu sou o cliente. Recebo sempre no da 5. O meu melhor dia não pode ser o 5 para pagar, então escolho o dia 10.

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus Consegui explicar?

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus Consegui explicar?

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus Se você poder me ajudar, ficarei imensamente grato.

Comment: posso, mas acho que não hoje mais. vou fazer compras daquia apouco

Comment: @ViniciusDeJesus blz, a medida que for evoluindo aqui vou atualizando esse post.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96368/discussion-between-vinicius-de-jesus-and-tiago).

Comment: Qual o problema com o código corrente ?

Answer (score 3):

Certamente existem formas melhores de fazer isso, não sou especialista em JS, longe disso. Na verdade estou fazendo um curso de JS atualmente, e fiquei ontem e hoje um bom tempo quebrando a cabeça nesta pergunta pra treinar hehe.

Então como acho que até ficou decente, e como quem sabe pode ajudar o AP, segue abaixo a solução que encontrei com a ajuda de várias perguntas/respostas daqui, do SO e outros sites citados abaixo.

Algumas considerações sobre as diferenças com o seu código:

- Utilizei o [`date`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) para gerar as datas, só incrementando o mês
  inicial parece impossível;
- Utilizei o `let`para declarar as variáveis, pois quando você declara
  sem nada ela fica com o escopo global;
- Utilizei o [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) para formatar a data;
- Utilizei o [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) para escrever o valor em R$;
- Criei um botão e utilizei um evento `click` pra ficar mais fácil de testar (inclusive já deixei alguns values nos inputs do snnipet abaixo);
- Não há necessidade de fazer `!= ""` para testar se foi inserido algum valor para entrar no `if`, basta colocar entre parênteses que o JS já verifica se o valor é `true` ou `false`;

```js
  $('#calcular').click(function() {
    
    let valorCurso = parseFloat($("#valorCurso").val());
    let valorPago = parseFloat($("#valorPago").val()).toFixed(2);
    let parcelas = parseInt($("#parcelas").val());
    let melhorDia = parseInt($("#melhorDia").val());

    if ((valorCurso) && (valorPago) && (parcelas)) {

      // ENCONTRA O VALOR LÍQUIDO

     let valorLiquido = parseFloat(valorCurso - valorPago);

      // CALCULA A PARCELA

     let valorParcela = parseFloat(valorLiquido / parcelas);
  
     let table = '';
     let par = 1;

     // ENCONTRA A DATA ATUAL

     let hoje = new Date();

     // CRIA A DATA NO MÊS SEGUINTE COM O MELHOR DIA

     let primeiraParcela = new Date(hoje.getFullYear(), hoje.getMonth() + 1, melhorDia);

        for(i = 0; i < parcelas; i++) {
          table += '<tr><td>' + par  + '</td>';
          table += '<td>' + primeiraParcela.toLocaleDateString() + '</td>';
          table += '<td>' + valorParcela.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 , style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' }) + '</td></tr>';
          par++;
          primeiraParcela.setMonth(primeiraParcela.getMonth() + 1); // AUMENTA UM MÊS      
        }

   $('#tabelaParcelas tbody').html(table);

    }
  });
```

```css
tr, th, td {

padding: 5px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-BR'>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Valor</label>
        <input id="valorCurso" name="valorCurso" type="text" class="form-control moeda" value="100" required/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Entrada</label>
        <input id="valorPago" name="valorPago" type="text" class="form-control moeda" value="0" required/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Parcelas</label>
        <input id="parcelas" name="parcelas" type="number" class="form-control" value="7" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Melhor dia</label>
        <select id="melhorDia" name="melhorDia" class="form-control">
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">
          <button type="button" id="calcular" class="btn btn-default">Calcular</button>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="clearfix form-actions">
      <table id="tabelaParcelas">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Parcela</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</body>
 </html>
```

Referências:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989579/how-do-add-days-to-a-date

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

[Calcular valores em real R$](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62524/calcular-valores-em-real-r)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49265311/how-to-get-a-specify-date-in-every-month-in-javascript

Comment: Até mais completa que a minha, mas eu respondi primeiro.

Answer (score 1):

Explicações nos comentários no código, qualquer dúvida é só adicionar um comentário.

```js
$("#melhorDia").change(function() {
  let valor = $("#valorCurso").val();
  let pago = $("#valorPago").val();
  let parcelas = $("#parcelas").val();
  let bestDay = $("#melhorDia").val();
  let diferenca = valor - pago;
  let valorParcelas = diferenca / parcelas;

  //instancia de data atual
  data = new Date();
  //No JS os meses são representados de 0 à 11, ou seja precisamos adicionar + 1
  mesAtual = data.getMonth() + 1;

  //limpo o corpo da tabela
  $("#corpo-tabela").empty()

  for (var i = 1; i <= parcelas; i++) {

    //O (i-1) serve para que os meses acompanhem a iteração e sejam somados a quantidade de parcelas, mas que como começa com 1
    // estou sutraindo 1
    $("#corpo-tabela").append("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + valorParcelas + "</td><td>" + bestDay + "/" + (mesAtual + (i - 1)) + "</td>")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Valor</label>
          <input id="valorCurso" name="valorCurso" type="text" class="form-control moeda" value="" required/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Valor pago</label>
          <input id="valorPago" name="valorPago" type="text" class="form-control moeda" value="" required/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Parcelas</label>
          <input id="parcelas" name="parcelas" type="number" class="form-control" value="" required/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Melhor dia</label>
          <select id="melhorDia" name="melhorDia" class="form-control">
            <option value="">SELECIONE</option>
            <option value="05">05</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="space-4"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <label class="control-label">Parcelas</label>
        <table class="table" id="tabelaParcelas">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Parcela</th>
              <th>Valor</th>
              <th>Data</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="corpo-tabela">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Vinicius, reparei em um problema. Se eu parcelo em 15x a coluna data fica errada. Aparece mês acima de 12. Outro detalhe, deixar no formato yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Na verdade eu já entreguei sabendo deste problema, mas vc queria que eu fizesse o trabalho todo por você? Negativo.